# Merging a Trunk into a Forked Branch

Tags: svn, version-control, branch, fork, trunk

Hopefully this makes sense: In subversion if I branch a trunk and then fork the branch can I merge changes from the trunk into the forked branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really not very much different from merging from trunk into a "regular" branch. The only difference is that the branched branch will be rooted in a branch instead of trunk. If you're using Subversion 1.6 with merge tracking, you can do:

```
$ svn copy ^/trunk ^/branches/mybranch
... hack away in trunk ...
$ svn copy ^/branches/mybranch ^/branches/myforkedbranch
... hack away in trunk

# Merge from trunk to myforkedbranch
$ cd myforkedbranch-workingcopy
$ svn merge ^/trunk .
```